# How to find directories of all the links on a website using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to find broken links by using

```
driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

but the problem is it only find links present on a home page. is there any way to find directory of all the links available on a webpage?

Comment: Can you be more specific? That should find all the anchor tags on the present page; what behavior are you seeing?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch right now it only find url's on home page let say "abc.com" but there are many links present under those url's. how to get those links? is there any method to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function to find all the links on a webpage using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447074/function-to-find-all-the-links-on-a-webpage-using-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find broken links using Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414150/how-to-find-broken-links-using-selenium)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no these are not duplicates. "How to find broken links using Selenium" - this only find links on the main page but what i am asking how to loop all the links(sub links) on a web page.

Comment: It's the same question; you seem to be missing the idea of recursing into the links from the home page.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ok do you have any idea how to do that? broken links on all the links available on a website?

Comment: @Learningcode Yes. Recurse into the links. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20399211/2970947) is a C# example.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch do you know how to do it in java?

Answer (score 0):

List down all the links

```
driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

Then load each url on new browser window or same window and do this recursively. Keep adding new links and add only new links in list.

If you have other option better use Java/Perl for this task.